# Masm32 вывод на консоль

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Как сделать корректный вывод на консоль?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
include includes\masm32.inc
include includes\msvcrt.inc
include includes\win32k.inc
include includes\kernel32.inc
include includes\macros\macros.asm
include includes\user32.inc

includelib includes\masm32.lib
includelib includes\kernel32.lib
includelib includes\win32k.lib
includelib includes\msvcrt.lib
includelib includes\user32.lib

.data
y   db  -15
Pi  dq  3
tpt db  'y=%d, Pi =%d', 10,0
.code
start: 

    invoke  crt_printf, ADDR tpt, [y], [Pi]
   invoke  crt__getch
     invoke  crt_exit,0
    end start
```

Выводит совсем не те данные

Comment: Какие данные выводит?

Comment: 241 и 0,00034. @insolor

Answer (score 3):

Ваша программа не может выводить `0,00034`, если конечно у вас вместо второго `%d` не какой-то другой спецификатор. У меня выводит `y=241, Pi =196608`.

Почему выводит не то что нужно?

Под дизассемблером смотрим, что нам нагенерировал ассемблер:

```
.text:00401000 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00401000
.text:00401000 ; Attributes: noreturn
.text:00401000
.text:00401000                 public start
.text:00401000 start           proc near
.text:00401000                 push    dword_403005
.text:00401006                 push    dword_403001
.text:0040100C                 push    0
.text:0040100E                 mov     al, byte_403000
.text:00401013                 movzx   ax, al
.text:00401017                 push    ax
.text:00401019                 push    offset Format   ; "y=%d, Pi =%d\n"
.text:0040101E                 call    ds:printf
.text:00401024                 add     esp, 10h
.text:00401027                 call    ds:_getch
.text:0040102D                 push    0               ; Code
.text:0040102F                 call    ds:exit
.text:0040102F start           endp

...

.data:00403000 byte_403000     db 0F1h                 ; DATA XREF: start+Er
.data:00403001 dword_403001    dd 3                    ; DATA XREF: start+6r
.data:00403005 dword_403005    dd 0                    ; DATA XREF: startr
.data:00403009 ; char Format[]
.data:00403009 Format          db 'y=%d, Pi =%d',0Ah,0 ; DATA XREF: start+19o
```

Сначала ассемблер честно кладет на стек два дворда (т.е. один `qword`, размер переменной заданный в исходном коде с помощью `dq`). Дальше на стек зачем-то кладется 0, потом исходная байтовая переменная расширяется до одинарного слова, при чем без учета знака (`movzx` - переместить с добиванием слева нулями), потом кладет это слово на стек, причем это одинарное слово автоматически расширяется до двойного, опять же без учета знака. После этого на стек кладется адрес строки форматирования, и вызывается функция `printf`.

После вызова функции стек выравнивается (по соглашению [**`cdecl`**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#cdecl)) на величину отправленных в стек параметров. В данном случае выравнивается на 16 байт (10h), хотя должно выровняться на 5 пушей * 4 байта = 20 байт.

Все выглядит довольно странно. Создается впечатление, что макросы масма не везде учитывают, что мы работаем в 32-битном, а не в 16-битном режиме.

Пробуем заменить `db` и `dq` на `dd`, и собрать. Результат - `y=-15, Pi =3`, то что и требовалось. Дизассемблер также показывает ожидаемый код:

```
.text:00401000                 public start
.text:00401000 start           proc near
.text:00401000                 push    dword_403004
.text:00401006                 push    dword_403000
.text:0040100C                 push    offset Format   ; "y=%d, Pi =%ld\n"
.text:00401011                 call    ds:printf
.text:00401017                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:0040101A                 call    ds:_getch
.text:00401020                 push    0               ; Code
.text:00401022                 call    ds:exit
.text:00401022 start           endp
```

Что делать если хочется выводить именно байт и четверное слово?

Использование спецификаторов, специально предназначенных для байта и для четверного слова (`tpt db  'y=%hhd, Pi =%lld', 10,0`) само по себе не помогает. Поэтому попробуем передавать параметры вручную, не надеясь на работу стандартных макросов:

```
.data
y   db  -15
Pi  dq  3
; %lld обязательно нужно указать, чтобы printf знал, что на стеке лежит два двойных слова
tpt db  'y=%d, Pi =%lld', 10,0
.code
start:
    push dword ptr [Pi+4]
    push dword ptr [Pi]
    movsx eax, [y]  ; Расширяем байт до двойного слова с учетом знака
    push eax
    push offset tpt
    call crt_printf
    add esp, 10h  ; 4 пуша по 4 байта = 16 = 10h

    invoke  crt__getch
    invoke  crt_exit,0
end start
```

На печать выходит:

```
y=-15, Pi =3
```

Теперь, если вернуться к тому, что мы видели в процессе дизассемблирования первого варианта - макросы на стек умеют правильно класть `qword`, поэтому достаточно заранее подготовить для вывода только байт, а функцию вызвать через `invoke`:

```
movsx eax, [y]  ; Расширяем байт до двойного слова с учётом знакового бита 
invoke crt_printf, addr tpt, eax, [Pi]
```

Результат тоже будет

```
y=-15, Pi =3
```